# TFS API: Error thrown while triggering custom build using label

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, msbuild

I am trying to trigger build using TFS API. I need to trigger build based on Label. Code is like:

```
WorkItemStore workItemStore = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
Project teamProject = workItemStore.Projects["TFSProjName"];
IBuildServer buildServer = tfs.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer)) as IBuildServer;
IBuildDefinition buildDef = buildServer.GetBuildDefinition(teamProject.Name, "MyTestBuild");
IBuildRequest req = buildDef.CreateBuildRequest();
req.GetOption = GetOption.Custom;
req.CustomGetVersion = "LABC_2.0.389@$/TFSProjName";
buildServer.QueueBuild(req);
```

In my build definition, server path of Build Process Template is provide (which is not part of `LabelName` i am providing above).
When run, it shows following error:

> TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition     \TFSProjName\MyTestBuild: Item $/TFSProjName/BuildProcessTemplates/NewBuildProcessTemplate.xaml was not found in source control at version LABC_2.0.389@$/TFSProjName.

When i trigger the same build using Visual Studio, it works fine. I am not sure how to explicitly direct system to check `BuildProcessTemplate` which is not part of label i am providing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is similar to [this case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/33cab528-f25d-4880-b24c-7b7c3e8c79af/tf215097-tfs-2010-build-by-label-build-process-template-not-found-in-source-control-at-version?forum=tfsbuild), please check the solution in it:

> I fixed the problem by adding the missing build process template to
>   the label I want to build. So, I basically replace the logic with the
>   following:

```
// Check if a label was specified for the build; otherwise, use latest.
if (!labelName.IsEmptyOrNull())
{
  // Ensure the build process template is added to the specified label to prevent TF215097.
  AppendBuildProcessTemplateToLabel(tpc, buildDefinition, labelName);
  // Request the build of a specific label.
  buildRequest.GetOption = GetOption.Custom;
  buildRequest.CustomGetVersion = "L" + labelName;
}
I created the following method to append the build process template to the label prior to queueing a build.

/// <summary>
/// Appends the build process template to the given label.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="teamProjectCollection">The team project collection.</param>
/// <param name="buildDefinition">The build definition.</param>
/// <param name="labelName">Name of the label.</param>
private static void AppendBuildProcessTemplateToLabel(TfsConnection teamProjectCollection, IBuildDefinition buildDefinition, string labelName)
{
  // Get access to the version control server service.
  var versionControlServer = teamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
  if (versionControlServer != null)
  {
    // Extract the label instance matching the given label name.
    var labels = versionControlServer.QueryLabels(labelName, null, null, true);
    if (labels != null && labels.Length > 0)
    {
      // There should only be one match and it should be the first one.
      var label = labels[0];
      if (label != null)
      {
        // Create an item spec element for the build process template.
        var itemSpec = new ItemSpec(buildDefinition.Process.ServerPath, RecursionType.None);
        // Create the corresponding labe item spec element that we want to append to the existing label.
        var labelItemSpec = new LabelItemSpec(itemSpec, VersionSpec.Latest, false);
        // Create the label indicating to replace the item spec contents. This logic will append
        // to the existing label if it exists.
        versionControlServer.CreateLabel(label, new[] {labelItemSpec}, LabelChildOption.Replace);
      }
    }
  }
}
```